# Confusion on ARM-Tiva PORTS and Registers

Tags: arm, tm4c123g

So im learning the Edx Embedded course "Shape the World", it's very good so far and im really learning a lot.

Im in the section (6) learning about Ports and Registers. And maybe im a bit confused at what a "Port" exactly is.

Here is a quick capture from the "Ports" table (Specifically Port F which we are using): [PORT F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIsBo.jpg)

I mostly understand the registers, They are 32 bit (With most bits being reserved besides the first 8 (0-7). Like DEN enabling pins and so forth. But I guess Im confused in this instance.....what is a PIN, and what exactly is a PORT?

these are parallel ports right? Would the Serial Ports only have..2 registers with less than 32 bits (since tx/rx/clk is all you need on serial right?)

maybe im just a bit lost at functionally what the PORT vs PIN is. I understand what a register is (32 flip flops basically in this instance), but im making sure I understand the fundamentals before I go any further.

Secondary as a question, why does the image I attached show like 5 DEN registers for 1 port? What would be the point of that?

Comment: A pin is a physical connection on the IC which can be used to input or output a single data bit (The IC will also have pins for power, ground, and misc other things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A port is a group of pins -- typically eight or sixteen of them.

A register is a location in memory which controls a peripheral on the microcontroller. Some of those peripherals are GPIO peripherals, which allow you to control I/O on pins. Each port has its own GPIO peripheral (e.g, GPIOA, GPIOB, etc).

For instance, a typical GPIO peripheral will have one register to control whether each pin is an input or an output, one register to control what data is being output, one read-only register to represent the input data, and probably at least a couple other registers to control pull-up/down, slew speed, AFIO selection, and whatnot.

"Serial ports" and "parallel ports" are terms from personal computers. They don't really apply to microcontrollers; there are a variety of commonly available I/O peripherals which can be used in serial and/or parallel modes.

(What you're thinking of as a "serial port" is usually represented in a microcontroller as a UART or USART peripheral. They can be connected to pins which are "borrowed" from GPIO peripherals, but typically have quite a lot of different registers internally.)

The table in the image you've linked is… kind of useless. You should probably take a look at the datasheet for the microcontroller you're using; it'll probably explain things a lot better than that table.

Answer (score 2):

A **port** is a loose term for a grouping of external I/O. In addition to the GPIO ports, you can have UART, SPI, USB, Ethernet etc. Thinking of parallel and serial might be useful at an introductory educational level where you can start thinking about the wide/narrow trade-off, but these terms are best viewed as relative approximations and not hard and fast distinctions. Behind any port, you're likely to have some peripheral logic which handles the detailed behaviour (direction and value for a simple port or buffers and low level protocol details
for a dedicated port with a specific function).

A **pin** is an individual place in a circuit. Generally the external connections to an ASIC or a component, but it can also be used to describe internal nodes if the context is right. Ports generally consist of several pins.

**Registers** is the most overloaded of these terms. You can have the following meanings at least:

- the core 'architectural' registers R1-R14 and the PC (which is a virtual register). These are 32 bit.
- the core architectural control registers which influence debug, core states, memory mapping etc. These can be either memory mapped or co-processor mapped (except in Cortex-M, where only memory mapped implementation is supported). These are mostly word-aligned, but may not use all of the bits in each word. Generally they behave like memory.
- Peripheral control registers. These are memory mapped but might not behave like memory. There might be a buffer, read and write might have different functions, they may be sensitive the the act of reading or writing (clear on read for example for a status bit). They are generally word-aligned, but not always use all 32 bits.
- Registers are also the low-level storage cells, often called flip-flops. These are individual bits or arrays of bits (can be any size). There are far more of these in a design than you would expect from summing all the instances of the other 3 cases listed above.

Your image describes a 20 bit port, with a DEN control for each pin (at least that is my guess). For some reason, the bits in the control registers are places in 4 byte groups in the table.

A GPIO port will typically consist of an array of similar pins, each one having an independent control. The reason for this (and another reason to avoid the 'parallel port' moniker) is that each one or two pins on this port may have a dedicated purpose. Some pins might use the alternate functions (and be wired to a different peripheral), some might be used for switch inputs, some for LED control, some for chip-select to complement an I2C peripheral. Some pins on the GPIO might even be used as internal controls for a device.